# Why my dialouge system won't load the 2nd sentences on Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this problem with my code in that it works well with when I press E to talk, showing the canvas and the continue button but when I press the continue button it doesn't show me the next sentence.

Here is the code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using System.Collections;

public class Dialogue : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI textDisplay;
    public string[] sentences;
    private int index;
    public float typingSpeed;
    public bool playerIsClose;
    public GameObject dialoguePanel;
    public GameObject continueButton;

    private void Update ( )
    {
        if ( Input.GetKeyDown ( KeyCode.E ) && playerIsClose )
        {
            continueButton.SetActive ( true );
            if ( dialoguePanel.activeInHierarchy )
            {
                zeroText ( );
            }
            else
            {
                dialoguePanel.SetActive ( true );
            }
        }
    }

    public void zeroText ( )
    {
        dialoguePanel.SetActive ( false );
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D ( Collider2D other )
    {
        if ( other.CompareTag ( "Player" ) )
        {
            playerIsClose = true;
        }
    }

    private void Start ( )
    {
        StartCoroutine ( Type ( ) );
    }

    IEnumerator Type ( )
    {
        foreach ( char letter in sentences [ index ].ToCharArray ( ) )
        {
            textDisplay.text += letter;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds ( typingSpeed );
        }
    }

    public void NextSentence ( )
    {
        continueButton.SetActive ( false );

        if ( index < sentences.Length - 1 )
        {
            index++;
            textDisplay.text = " ";
            StartCoroutine ( Type ( ) );
        }
        else
        {
            zeroText ( );
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D ( Collider2D other )
    {
        if ( other.CompareTag ( "Player" ) )
        {
            playerIsClose = false;
            zeroText ( );
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to put `index++;` in other places and put `zeroText ()` to try and see if it really the problem or not turns out it's still broken.

Comment: Im surprised you havent had issues calling the method Type. However. You never call next sentence so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many sentences are stored in the array? I'm guessing two?! Take a look at your `if` statement inside `NextSentence()`: `index` which starts at 0 will be checked against the `length` of the array **-1**. This will always cause the last sentence in the array to be ignored.

Either remove the -1 or change the < into a <=.

Someone else noticed that you never use `NextSentence()`, but I guess you do it via a button?!